# Removing a regular expression from a bash variable

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bash variable that looks like

```
aaa-bb-cccc-r17, m12w_pp_r2, z-r123, etc.
```

I am looking to extract everything up to the (final) -rNNN (any number of digits), or in other words, remove the final -rNNN. If the variable does not end in -r followed by a number, I want to leave it unchanged.

I tried ${the_variable%-r[0-9]*} but it turns out the * is the shell * ("match anything") rather than the regular expression * ("match any number of occurrences of previous element"). Using + instead of * ("one or more") matched nothing.

Any solution (along this line or any other)?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with extended pattern support.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ the_variable=aaa-bb-cccc-r17
$ echo "${the_variable%-r+([0-9])}"
aaa-bb-cccc
```

Answer (score 1):

As you found parameter expansion can't, directly, do what you want here.

You could play games with stripping everything up to the last `-` in the value and then checking that the remaining string matches your desired pattern but at that point you might as well just do the pattern match directly and be done.

```
$ pat='(.*)-r[0-9]*$'
$ var='aaa-bb-cccc-r17, m12w_pp_r2, z-r123'
$ [[ $var =~ $pat ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="aaa-bb-cccc-r17, m12w_pp_r2, z"
$ var='aaa-bb-cccc-r17, m12w_pp_r2, z-r123g'
$ [[ $var =~ $pat ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ declare -p var
declare -- var="aaa-bb-cccc-r17, m12w_pp_r2, z-r123g"
```